# Windows 7 Boot Error 0x0000007B

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I fear I've messed up and hope this can be resolved. Here is the [video](https://youtu.be/xXeDmaAP5x4) of what happens what I boot my computer. The boot sequence gets to the Windows logo and then crashes with the error shown above in the title.

I tried the solutions [on HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) however, none of the commands `bootrec /fixmbr` & `bootrec /fixboot` worked. I have tried safe mode, repair on local & USB Windows 7, yet still no fix. The additional issue is that when I load up Windows 7 Bootable USB, the OS fails to find any hard drive!

The following image shows that the system recovery doesn't find any Windows installation either.

[image]

*Notes:*
I was fiddling with the Windows 7 Disk Management making space for Ubuntu before this happened. I initially shrunk the C (primary) drive partition, then later remerged (extended) the C partition to include the newly created empty partition.

I really do not want to lose the data on C !

Comment: Check SATA Mode in BIOS. Should be set to AHCI

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Im browsing through the BIOS right now & cant seem to find any such settings. Under 'Drives', under 'SATA-0', my HD is as followings : `controller = Serial ATA`, `port = SATA-0`, `BIOS : This device is controller by the RAID BIOS`. I can only turn it On / Off, & its currently 'On'.

Comment: Which computer do you have ?

Comment: its a Dell XPS820, Core2Duo, 2GB Ram. A true powerhouse during its time :)

Comment: Quite unlikely you don't have that option but cannot find a screenshot or emulators to show you. Neither i have this computer model

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Changed SATA Mode in BIOS from AHCI to ATA, and it booted right up. Dell XPS M1300.